# SQS queue listener (Springboot)

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-aws

How to control request with SQS. Suppose 4 request submitted in a same time in SQS, then only need to process one at a time. Once first is completes take second request from queue in process, and this process needs to continue.

I was using @SqsListener in springboot to get message payload.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I dont know how to control request. Any idea how we can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory bean](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/main/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory.java) and configure the listener behavior as follows:

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    [...]
    factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);
    factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(1);
    [...]

    return factory;
}
```

Comment: Hi tried the above approach but that's not working. Thats executing all requests in parallel.